# $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)\neq 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

I ask help to fix my confusion: I understand that the arithmetic genus of a connected Riemann surface is $h^1(X,\mathcal O_X)$. Now, why is this not zero? Can someone give me an example of a Cech cocycle that does not vanish in cohomology?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give a bit of your background ? Do you know how to compute the Cech cohomology of the projective curve defined by the homogeneous equation $Y^2Z=X(X-Z)(X-2Z)$ for instance ? This curve has an affine cover by two open subset $U_1=\{Z\neq 0\}$ and $U_2=\{Y\neq 0\}$. In these two subsets $X^2/YZ$ is a cocyle.

Comment: This suffices, thanks!